# Using copyin when threadprivate variable is defined in another file

Tags: multithreading, static, openmp

I create a struct in a .h file (declarations.h)

*

```
struct TdynGlobal {
private:
  int num_sections_;
public:
  static int id_section_;
}
extern TdynGlobal tdyn_global_;
```

*

In the .cc (declarations.h) file I defined id_section as threadprivate variable:

*

```
int TdynGlobal::id_section_ = -1;
#pragma omp threadprivate(TdynGlobal::id_section_)
```

*

At the beginnig of program I create two sections where I give different values for id_section:

*

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
        {
#pragma omp section
            {
                tdyn_global_.SetIdSection(0);
                tdynmain(nargs_tdyn, tdyn_args, resname_coupling);
            } // end section 1
#pragma omp section
            {
                tdyn_global_.SetIdSection(1);
                tdynmain(nargs_tdyn, tdyn_args2, resname_coupling);
            } // end section 2
        } // end parallel sections
```

*

Inside both sections, each section has its own id_section value (0 or 1), but if I create a parallel region inside a section in a different file, I have threads where id_section=-1. Therefore, I define parallel regions using copyin clause:

*`#pragma omp parallel copyin(TdynGlobal::id_section_)`*

But I have this error:

> error C3058: 'id_section_' : symbol not declared as 'threadprivate'
>   before it is used in the 'copyin' clause

If I declare `TdynGlobal::id_section_` as threadprivate another time there is another error because it was declared in another file.

So I don't know what I can do to have the same value of id_section in all threads in a parallel region inside a section.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is the value that any given thread is supposed to have for `TdynGlobal::id_section_`? Like, I'm thread id number 7 of a parallel region: what is my private `TdynGlobal::id_section_` supposed to be? Failing to knowing that, it'll be difficult to give you any sort of advice.